# QuickReturnPattern with Listview and Layout

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to implement Roman Nurik's Quick Return Pattern.(https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt)

I found a lot of libraries and examples about this pattern but all of them adds quick return view into listview's header. i don't want to add my quick return view to listview's header. I already have a header in my listview.

Do you have any suggestions about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others who's trying to implement pattern i asked above, you can put an empty place holder to your listview's header as high as your quick return view. And you can scroll top together.

Here you can find an example project about it.
https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView